# How to realize Multisequence Alignment with BioPython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, sequence-alignment, protein-database

I have multiple strings representing protein sequences ( for example `ADADAAA`,`ADADDDCDAA` and `ACCC`), I want to realize MSA on those such that resulting sequences have the  same length. [Biopython documentation](https://biopython-cn.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/en/chr06.html) seems only  to explain how to handle already formed Multi aligned sequences.

Comment: Your link is for biopython alignment objects. Check here: https://biopython.org/wiki/AlignIO

Comment: @Ghoti `Bio.AlignIO` is only for *parsing* alignments, they want alignment tools like `from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline`